# How to search comma separated greater than or less than values in neo4j

Tags: c#, neo4j, cypher

Can we search greater than comma separated value in Cypher
Example:

```
MATCH (n:Field)
Where n.name = "square:" AND n.value > "12,196"
RETURN n
```

12,196 it means 12 thousand 1 hundred and 96 and i want to search greater than that value
can anyone help me

Comment: i have edited values , In database the values were saved like 12,196 and i want to search greater than that value is it possible?

Comment: please help me it's too urgent

Comment: store the value as a integer or float and then you can easily search for greater than values

Comment: i also tried this MATCH (n:Field) Where n.name = "square:" AND toFloat(n.value) > toFloat("12,196") RETURN n LIMIT 25  but not working

Comment: actually the datatype of n.value is string in database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, `toFloat` / `toInteger` do not accept locales, you won't be able to parse the comma properly with that function.

As Tomaž suggested in the comment, migrate the values first (back up your data first!):

```
MATCH (n:Field)
SET n.value = toFloat(replace(n.value, ",", "")) # or toInteger
```

And then change your query to:

```
MATCH (n:Field)
WHERE n.name = "square:" AND n.value > 12196
RETURN n
```